# Trying to do some assertion from request, which will be present in response

Tags: rest, api, karate

I am passing the request as  in my feature file and i am trying to do assert from request to response.

I have tried must contains queries but i am not sure if i am doing it correct, could you please help.

```
**Background:**
*  configure headers = read('classpath:merchantServiceheaders.js')

Given url MservUrl 
And path '/spapis/rest/sp-ms-engine/sp/ms/v1/engine/scanandredact'
```

**Scenario Outline: ACH Low Value Payment Rips Services Summary**

]
}***

What i would like to do is assert what i have in my request to what i will get back in response.

Since i am passing subject in request the same subject should be present in response

Comment: And if it's not possible, how can i just do it with just simple request and response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible in 0.9.3: https://github.com/intuit/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements

First change the `Examples:` column header to `data!`

```
And request data
When method post
Then status 200 
And match response contains data
```

In 0.9.2 and earlier, with the Examples: column header as `data`

```
* def data = <data>
And request data
When method post
Then status 200 
And match response contains data
```

Comment: oh ok, internal in our firm we are only allowed 0.9.0, is there a work around,

Comment: @sadiqkassamali that is a stupid decision IMO, anyway see my edit

Comment: We upgraded to version 0.9.3 , so we will be implementing your original reply